# In Android , how to use the condition based on the sum of 2 columns' values operation in the where clause using SqliteDatabase 's query() method

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I need to execute query in Android using SqliteDataBase's query() method.
I need to get rows which depends on 2 columns' combined condition.

I tried the following code :

```
String whereClause = " colA = ? and (colB + colC*100) >= ?";
String[]  values = { String.valueOf(0), String.valueOf(20)};

Cursor cursor = db.query("<table_name>", new String[] {colA,colB,colC}, whereClause,    values, null, null, "startDate");
```

Query is executed successfully but not fetching the results according to the "AND" condition specified in the where condition. It seems it is not looking at that AND condition 
    (colB + colC*100 >= ?).

When I replaced the placeholders (?) by the exacts values specified in the "values" variable then it is working fine . Also using rawQuery() , it is goving results.

But my requirement is to use the same method (query()).

Please can anybody tell me the way to use that where condition successfully?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try surrounding your clause with extra parantheses like this:
(colA = ?) AND (colB + colC*100 >= ?)

Comment: Yeah , I tried that too.